# Python GData Import

Tags: python, gdata

I'm trying to use gdata python but unfortunately when I execute my script it keeps on saying me "ImportError: No module named docs".

I have tried importing it by running python directly in shell and everything seems fine.

Can someone help me out with this problem?

edit:

```
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.client
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
```

Comment: how are you using the `gdata.docs`? are you writing `docs.thing` or `gdata.docs.thing`? Try using the latter if you arn't already.

Comment: Nope, the problem isn't how I use it because I installed gdata on my local machine and the exact same script works like a charm

Comment: It may be a version issue then, sorry I can't help more, someone else will know more hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem when I started. My guess is that  your Gdata library is not on your Python path. For example, my gdata and atom modules are located in the Python27/Lib/site-packages folder.

Another option is to update your PATH environmental variable to point to the current location of the Gdata files.